# How to judge whether today is Sunday in Linux Shell Scripts?

Tags: linux, shell

I use these to judge Sunday in shell:

```
week=`date -d $day +%w`
month=`date -d "-1 day ago $day" '+%d'`

if [ "$week" = "0" ];then
if [ "$month" = "01" ];then
```

But when $day is 20171103 , It was regarded as Sunday , then the 20171105 was missed.

Then I run "date -d 20171105 +%w" in the server ,it shows 0, and the if caluse was true. Then I check the Time Zone , Time Zone was right ,+0800

Are there any better methods in shell that can solve this problem? More safer and robust to judge whether the string like YYYYMMDD is Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `date %u` for day of the week?

There are plenty of options in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date).